# How can I control static analyzed compiler error messages with templated libraries?

Tags: c++, clang

Today I learned that most compilers offer static analysis like

```
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++1y -Werror -Weverything -Wno-documentation -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-padded")
```

Which I think is really cool but I am also using some templated libraries which of course are header only.

Now I just can't use those flags anymore because those libraries are full of "errors/warnings". I could try to find all those flags and disable them but would really like to have those errors/warnings in my code.

Is there a workaround for this? I thought maybe I could try to find all template instantiations, compile the header file with no compiler warnings and then link the precompiled header with my code.

Do you think that could be possible?

Comment: Off topic, but `-Weverything` is not the flag that you might expect, especially used with `-Werror`; `gcc` doesn't provide the flag so it's not portable. It's supposed that `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align` should suffice for most of the case.

Comment: @HongxuChen oh my somehow I missed the `-Weverything` earlier, note that it is not [meant to be used outside of clang development](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/124574/84604).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both gcc and clang support [Diagnostic Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) which will allow you to ignore specific diagnostic messages for a section of code. For example to disable `-Wunused-variable` like so:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
// include headers with warnings
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

this is very useful for third part libraries where you don't have control of the code.